# AWS Cloudwatch set up WebHook

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-post, webhooks, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch

I am having trouble in defining a webhook on AWS CloudWatch(I am new to this technology). I checked out a lot of forums but I could not find out the right answer. Basically, what I need is a webhook or a similar way for sending an alert from CloudWatch to a web server via http post, every time the alert is generated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure CloudWatch to send the alert to an SNS topic. Then have SNS send the message to an [HTTP endpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html).

Comment: I am stuck with the same problem but your solution is not usable: said webhooks are generally not owned by whoever triggers them (this is the whole point of webhooks, so that ONE can HOOK into WEB services of OTHERS/3rd parties). That being said: SNS can NOT be implemented since the strategy of SNS requires the HTTP endpoint to CONFIRM subscription. As I said, I cannot modify the http endpoint so that it returns a confirmation response to SNS. :/  Any other ideas ?

Comment: @JonaRodrigues please ask a separate question on here instead of tacking onto this one.